# setting a different src picture in a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change a picture in a webpage using the tag `button` and the `onclick` attribute that call a function that I did in a js document, but it isn't working, this is what a did:

in Javascript:

```
function store (a,z) {
  var pic;
  if (a>z) {
       pic = "images_weddings/desing_logo-01.jpg";
  }else{
       pic = "images_weddings/rose1.jpg";
  }
  document.getElementById('change1').src = pic;
}
```

and in html:

MATRIMONIOS

```
  <div>
      <img src="images_weddings/desing_logo-01.png" id="change1" >
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="store(2,3)">change the image</button>
```

Comment: What is happening? Does the image not change? Does it not load any image? Are there any errors in your console? After the change, if you inspect the HTML, does it have the new value?

Comment: The image doesn't change, just show what I put in the src of the html document, but regarding the change with the onclick nothing happens, the console doesn't show any error, regarding the last question, I don't know how to inspect the webpage in order to see the new value, (I am really new in this matters)

Comment: @Javier is some answer helps you then not forget to accept it by click on big gray check button (only 1 answer). If you whish you can also click on gray upper triangle of any answer you want to add +10 points to its author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change links to images and code works - strange in your code is that in html you have PNG file "desing_logo-01.png" but in js you have JPG file "desing_logo-01.jpg"

```js
function store (a,z) {
  var pic;
  if (a>z) {
       pic = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ktlQrO2Sifg/maxresdefault.jpg";
  }else{
       pic = "https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/girls-whose-hotness-just-trumped-cute-89-photos-257.jpg?quality=85&strip=info&w=600";
  }
  document.getElementById('change1').src = pic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="store(2,3)">change the image</button>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ktlQrO2Sifg/maxresdefault.jpg" id="change1" >
</div>
```

Comment: so, why can't I see the change in laptop ?

Comment: maybe the paths to images and/or images names are wrong

Comment: I thought the same and I used absolute paths like you did but it didn't work, at least in my laptop... ( i am using Atom - live - server)

Comment: @Javier using absolute paths is not good - may be first try to put your images in same directory as your html file and use only `src="desing_logo-01.png"` (but look especially on extention PNG-JPG), if this will work then create directory `images_weddings` move images there and change path

Comment: The problem that I had is that I put two "id" attributes in the html, today I saw my mistake, I removed the second id and the function worked perfect.

Comment: @Javier ok, so the real reason was more "deep" in your project code so my answer only shows that your approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your lapy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<title> </title>

</head>
<body>

<div>
      <img src="images_weddings/desing_logo-01.png" id="change1" >
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="store(2,3)">change the image</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function store (a,z) {
  var pic;
  if (a>z) {
       pic = "images_weddings/desing_logo-01.png";
  }else{
       pic = "images_weddings/rose1.png";
  }
  document.getElementById('change1').src = pic;
}
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: The problem that I had is that I put two "id" attributes in the html, today I saw my mistake, I removed the second id and the function worked perfect. Thanks for your help.